# How to scan barcode in android

Tags: android

How to scan barcode in android device through an application.
If the android device is connected to an external bluetooh barcode scanner adapter.
What API's or sdk will be required for this.?

Actually I am new in android so there may be mistakes in my question too, so sorry for this.

But if there is any solution please tell me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: go through this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214186/android-how-to-use-zxing-based-qr-code-with-inbuilt-scanner/6214256#6214256

Comment: I'd guess the bluetooth SDKs and then the device-specific protocol for talking to the device.

Answer (score 10):

You can use **ZXING Library** or **Biggu Scanner**..., For Biggu Scanner check this [sample](http://shopsavvy.mobi/android/sdk/release/ScannerSDK.Android-Latest.zip)

Comment: Is Biggu Scanner is open source, can we freely use this in our applications ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest reading the following from the Android Developer Guide -  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html
2. I would think you would need to look into the bluetooth interface/api provided by the manufacturer of the scanner.

Comment: If you want to scan barcode from your android phone camera then you can use http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Comment: But then your app has a reliance on other apps that dont come default within the Android OS

Answer (score 0):

I have found iScandit barcode scanner that is better than ZXING and biggu scanner.these 2 are not work when Barcode is not directly in camera focus but iScandit works on this situation amazingly.

Answer (score 0):

### 2016 update

Not sure about Bluetooth-connected barcode scanners, but nowadays you probably don't need one. The current recommendation is to use the [Android Barcode API](https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview):

> The Barcode API detects barcodes in real-time, on device, in any orientation. It can also detect multiple barcodes at once.
>
> It reads the following barcode formats:
>
> - 1D barcodes: EAN-13, EAN-8, UPC-A, UPC-E, Code-39, Code-93, Code-128, ITF, Codabar
> - 2D barcodes: QR Code, Data Matrix, PDF-417, AZTEC
>
> It automatically parses QR Codes, Data Matrix, PDF-417, and Aztec values, for the following supported formats:
>
> - URL
> - Contact information (VCARD, etc.)
> - Calendar event
> - Email
> - Phone
> - SMS
> - ISBN
> - WiFi
> - Geo-location (latitude and longitude)
> - AAMVA driver license/ID

Answer (score -1):

This is advice for you. for scan bar code.

It may help you.

Install this app from market.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5nb29nbGUuenhpbmcuY2xpZW50LmFuZHJvaWQiXQ..

use this app within your application using intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");

startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```